# В TableView выводится не по одной записи, а по 6

Tags: массивы, swift, uitableview

Есть парсер, который смотрит на html-таблицу. После успешного парсинга данные выводятся в tableview, но их количество увеличивается ровно на 5. В чем может быть дело?

Мой код из git: https://github.com/golub1/timetable_1/tree/master/ZameniYGK

[image: изображение]

Comment: Скорее всего ошибки в парсинге, копайте туда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас

```
self.schedule.append(timetable)
```

внутри цикла, в котором идет проход по колонкам. Нужно вынести за этот цикл.

Comment: ваше решение помогло, но не то, которое вы указали в МР. Спасибо